# Android "Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList" with Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio and I got a "Resources$NotFoundException" being thrown on Android pre-Lollipop only. Here it is:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0100b7 a=2}
```

and '**0x7f0100b7**' in **R** file refers to '**colorAccent**'.
I believe this problem is with the appcompat support library. 
I've added it to the 'build.gradle' file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0"
}
```

This is the theme:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/bg_main</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/bg_main_darker</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/bg_dark</item>
</style>
```

and those colors exist in 'color.xml'.

Any idea?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Material Design specific properties but running on a system version, that is prior Material.

> Note: If your app uses the material theme but does not provide an
>   alternative theme in this manner, your app will not run on versions of
>   Android earlier than 5.0.

You have to provide an alternative theme like described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html), to run prior versions than 5.

E.g. provide in `res/values/colors.xml`:

```
<!-- extend one of the Theme.AppCompat themes -->
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- customize the color palette -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_blue_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_blue_700</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_green_A200</item>
</style>
```

In your question text, you are writing `color.xml` instead of [colors.xml](http://developer.android.com/samples/BasicMediaRouter/res/values/colors.html), maybe also part of your problem :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So what's the point of using support library.  I thought it will take care of style properties.

Comment: The support library brings backward compatibility for earlier versions than 2.1 (v7) including features like `ActionBar` : http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7